# Browser autocomplete for address fields in checkout

Tags: magento2

I am tryng to get browser autocomplete ([The HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)
) to work for the checkout address fields but I am not having much success or many ideas.

Autocomplete does work for company and telephone fields but not for others - tested with chrome 86.

The only thing I tought to try was adding attribute autocomplete="given-name" to firstname field and that didn't work.

Has anyone done this already and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29507 → https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24712 I'm not quite sure whether or when this will appear in releases.